# Cross join two txt files in c#

Tags: c#, windows, forms

Hi I am new to c# and would like to achieve the following by cross joining the two files

File A contains:
Sam
Ram
Dam

File B contains:
Kumar
Kumari

I need to do a cross join of the two files and obtain the following results. Please note my files have millions of records and I need to achieve the same for all the records.

Samkumar
Samkumar
Ramkumar
Ramkumar
Damkumar
Damkumari

Expecting a generic and optimized way of handling it.

Comment: This works best if you try some code, and if it doesn't work show us the code, the results obtained. then we can help

Answer (score 0):

```
var fileA = File.ReadAllText("fileA.txt").Split(new[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.None);
var fileB = File.ReadAllText("fileB.txt").Split(new[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.None);

var join = (from a in fileA from b in fileB select a + b).ToArray();
// output
foreach(var x in join)
  Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Comment: Thanks notesjor, That really helped. But when I apply the same logic to a file that contains one word in each line with '\n' it is also giving me a result in two line...Am I missing something here.Also of you could please tell me how to write the same output in a new file.

Comment: To join a string array in C# use: string.Join(" ", join); The first argument " " is the separator for each item. If you use string.Join(";", join); you can build a CSV-file. To store the results File.WriteAllText("output.txt", string.Join(";", join));